# How to solve 400 bad request returned from XAMPP server

Tags: http, xampp, 400, bad-request

I am sending data from 2 devices. Data format from both device is similar. I have a XAMPP server running on Windows Server 2019.

Device One Server Log:

```
> 202.134.10.136 - - [28/Mar/2024:12:19:57 +0600] "GET /walton_rcrms/controller/devlogs.php/?data=1;01608984560;0;170,16,1,77,13,10,0,0,128,108,127,127,126,80,135,112,75,0,160,5,182,60,3,66,1,164,64,16,0,1,0,110,0,95,23,9,25,71,;187,2,0,0,1,62,231,0,0,0,127,127,126,80,135,112,75,0,160,5,182,60,3,66,1,164,64,16,0,1,0,110,0,95,23,9,25,14,;170,20,75,84,78,49,53,48,68,51,48,85,70,90,35,35,35,35,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,0,0,0,0,88,126,0,0,0,0,0,229,;;;0;
> HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "SIMCOM_MODULE"
```

Device Two Server Log:

```
> 202.134.10.139 - - [28/Mar/2024:12:19:55 +0600] "GET /walton_rcrms/controller/devlogs.php/?data=2;01608984559;0;170,16,1,30,13,1,0,0,128,104,129,127,128,124,130,118,19,0,160,3,167,41,2,66,1,159,47,16,0,1,0,110,2,84,23,9,25,190,;187,2,0,0,1,62,219,0,0,0,129,127,128,124,130,118,19,0,160,3,167,41,2,66,1,159,47,16,0,1,0,110,0,84,23,9,25,181,;170,20,75,84,78,49,53,48,68,51,48,85,70,90,35,35,35,35,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,32,0,0,0,88,126,0,0,0,177,117,11,;;;0;
> HTTP/1.1" 400 326 "-" "SIMCOM_MODULE"
```

Despite very similar data in both devices I am getting HTTP 400 response from server for Device Two.

Can any one help me to solve this problem.